# kendoUI Bar chart not rendering specified padding

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a bar chart that is not accepting the padding that should be placed around the plotArea as specified.

The expectation is to have a graph that has a few pixels between the bars and the axis lines. Everything is set up and renders as expected except the padding.

Here is a fiddle of what I have so far

http://jsfiddle.net/itanex/KdfUv/

```js
plotArea: {
   background: "none",
   padding: {
       left: 2,
       bottom: 2
   }
},
```

[image]

The arrows point to the padding that I want to apply between the axis lines and the graph bars

Comment: Please check below link. it may be help you to resolve your issue.http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/bar-charts/gap-spacing.html

Comment: That tutorial deals with the space between each of the bars. The space I want is that which is between the end of a bar and the axis line itself.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the works, but not so as you expect:

http://jsfiddle.net/fool/KdfUv/7/

```
    plotArea: {
        background: "yellow",
        padding: 10
    },
```

Comment: This does not add any padding between the bars and the axis lines. I am adding an image of what I am expecting.